Short Movie on PBS in the 70's with a Fox Stole that Comes to Life
When I was a kid in the 70's I remember very clearly seeing a short movie on our local Maine PBS station that had two kids (I think a girl and a boy) go down into the basement and look through boxes of old items, and they find some fox stoles (those scarves that are made of whole foxes, their heads and tails included) which proceed to come to life.  I think I got really scared at this point, so I really don't remember anything past this point. Any thoughts on what this might have possibly been?

live action or animated?

I remember a story that I read as a kid regarding a child who finds a fox stole in a cupboard in his bedroom.  He then picks lemons from a lemon tree outside and gives them to the fox (long story) which ends up bringing the fox to life. Turns out it is a short story called "Grandad's Gifts" from the book "Unbearable".  This story apparently was adapted for an episode by the same name of the kids TV show "Around The Twist" (season 2, episode 8). Does it sound familiar?

